# Assembly x86 pointer to array

Tags: arrays, pointers, assembly, x86

I am just playing around to understand how pointers in assembly language work, but I cannot find out how to make a pointer to array and later use it to print array.
So far I have:

```
section .data

    output db "%d",10,0
    array db 1, 2, 3, 4, 5     ;array of dwords
    sizeOf db 5                ;size of array
```

I somehow assume that I can make a pointer to array with the following code:

```
push array
mov esi, [esp]
```

Is this the way pointer to array is made? And how can I use it to print the whole array out?

Comment: `mov esi, array` will do.

Comment: so this doesn't actually copy the whole array and puts it in esi register, but just creates a pointer to it?

Comment: It couldn't possibly do that, now could it? An entire array of 5 DWORD-sized values couldn't fit into a single DWORD-sized register. It *has* to be storing a pointer to the array. If you think about it, you already knew that. You knew that `push` wasn't pushing the entire array onto the stack, it was just pushing a pointer. Same logic here.

Comment: Right... so now if I for example do: mov eax, [esi] I can move the first element of array into eax and mov eax, [esi+4] to get the second one right?

Comment: Yes, except that the items, as posted, are bytes (`db`). Beware.

Comment: Thank you I will try to do it this way.

Comment: How can I for example print first element of array using call _printf? All I am getting are weird addresses and cannot figure it out how to do it...